# MVC routing issue, need help to insert parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing, partial-views

I have a form in a partialView

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, new { controller = "Module", action="ModuleIndex", module="" }, FormMethod.Get, new { id = "frmMDR" }))
        {
            @Html.RadioButton("mdrSelector", "Maintenance", false, new { id = "rdoMaintenance" })<label for="rdoMaintenance">M</label>
            @Html.RadioButton("mdrSelector", "Diagnostics", false, new { id = "rdoDiagnostics" })<label for="rdoDiagnostics">D</label>
            @Html.RadioButton("mdrSelector", "Repair", false, new { id = "rdoRepair" })<label for="rdoRepair">R</label>
            @Html.Hidden("hdnVehicle", null, new { id="hdnVehicle"})
        }
```

When I choose a radio button, how can I populate the module parameter with the selected radio buttons value?  I'm using jQuery to submit the form on the radio buttons change event.

```
   $(':radio').change(function () {

            $('#frmMDR').submit();
        });
```

Here is my controller method

```
   public ActionResult ModuleIndex(string module)
    {

        switch (module)
        {
            case "Maintenance":
                return RedirectToRoute(new { area = module, controller = "Maintenance" });

            case "Diagnostics":
                return RedirectToRoute(new { area = module, controller = "Diagnostics" });

            case "Repair":
                return RedirectToRoute(new { area = module, controller = "Repair" });

            default:
                return RedirectToRoute(new { area = module, controller = "Maintenance" });

        }

    }
```

and lastly here is my routing config

```
   routes.MapRoute(
          "Module", // Route name
          "Module/ModuleIndex/{module}",
          new { controller = "Module", action = "ModuleIndex", module = "" }
          );
```

What am I not doing correctly? Any tips or help is always appreciated.

Kind Regards,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the first example on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.aspx) msdn site, the first string argument must be the same as the controller argument name:

```
@Html.RadioButton("module", "Maintenance", false)
@Html.RadioButton("module", "Diagnostics", false)
@Html.RadioButton("module", "Repair", false)
```

Comment: yes, this worked great. Thank you very much. I had to remove module token in my routevlaues as well. Anyways, thanks alot.

Comment: It wouldn't let me mark it correct at the time because I had just asked the question. But yes your answer was correct and I marked it as such. Thanks again friend! :)